# Python, append string as value

Tags: python

I am new to python, is there a way to append string in python as value.

For example:

```
b0 = str("123")
b1 = str("234")
b2 = str("345")
```

Easy for now. But in my special case, I have to doing somethings like this.

```
a = []
for i in range (0,3):
    z = str("b") + str("i")
    a.append(z)
```

My plan is when I print(a), it should somethings like ['123', '234', '345']. In fact, it doing like this['b0', 'b1', 'b2'].

So, how can I fix this.

Comment: Nope, Python doesn't work that way.  What you need is a dictionary.  Create `var['b0'] = "123"`, `var['b1'] = "234"`, `var['b2'] = "345"`.  That's the right way.  BTW, you do not need `str("123")`; that's already a string.

Comment: @FHLm Well, your example actually produces `['bi', 'bi', 'bi']`

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary.  Don't use `str` where it isn't required.

```
var['b0'] = "123"
var['b1'] = "234"
var['b2'] = "345"

a = []
for i in range(3):
    a.append(var[f"b{i}"])
```

Comment: it's a clean way to do that, just may instead of 3 (which, in this case, it's alright) `len(var)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
b_dict = {
    'b0': '123',
    'b1': '234',
    'b2': '345'
}

a = []
for i in range(3):
    z = 'b' + str(i)
    a.append(b_dict.get(z))
```

I'm also a beginner. She doesn't know why you're doing this, but that's one way I'm thinking about it, I'm going to use the dict.

Comment: `b_dict[z]` is good enough.  Don't need the "get" call.

Comment: but if using `b_dict[z]` , sometimes it will out of range. using get ,it will return None.

Answer (score -1):

```
a=[]
for i in range (0,3):
     z='%i%i%i' %(i,i+1,i+2)
     a.append(z)
```

Comment: `['123', '234', '345']` is a [mre], not the actual goal. The OP wants to iterate over the names of variables.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code?